# How to flatten two or more arrays in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, append

I am trying to run some quantitative analysis work with stock prices. so i chose some random stocks from the market in different years with matched criteria. This is where problem came in. I used `for loop` for years and put the results together, so the return is a [list of stocks tickers in 2020],[list of stocks tickers in 2019],[list of stocks tickers in 2018]...

DOM

```
>>>print(list(get_code_list()))
[array(['601677.SH', '000685.SZ', '600675.SH', '603018.SH',....], dtype=object),
array(['600230.SH', '600007.SH', '300068.SZ', '601369.SH',..., dtype=object)]
```

I wanna flatten them into one big list without duplicates, so that I can loop them to read csv files on my hardisk.

I also tried some methods, but it seems irrelavent to this matter.

```
def flatten(container):
    for x in container:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            for y in flatten(x):
                yield y
        else:
            yield x
```

or

```
import functools

functools.reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, stock_lists)
```

both methods didn't give me what i desire.
can someone help me with this matter?
Thank you, much appreciated.

my complete codes are posted below:

```
def get_code_list(years=None):
    samples = list()
    if years is None:
        years = list([20200212,20190222, ]) # 20180222, 20170222, 20160222
        backs = list()
        for i, year in enumerate(years, 1):
            dd = pro.daily_basic(trade_date=year)
            x1 = dd.close < 100
            x2 = dd.circ_mv > 400000  # 流通市值低于300亿大于50亿
            x3 = dd.circ_mv < 5000000
            x4 = dd.pb < 15  # 市净率低于15
            x5 = dd.pe_ttm < 100  # 市盈率低于100
            x6 = dd.dv_ttm > 1  # 股息率大于1%
            x = x1 & x2 & x3 & x4 & x5 & x6
            stock_list = dd[x].ts_code.values
            backs.append(stock_list)
        samples.append(backs)
#     return functools.reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,samples[:])
#     return flatten(samples)
```

Comment: The type of your expected output is a list, right?Does the order matter?

Comment: it matters because we can't loop two or more arrays in one list in one setting. We have to make sure it is one list, with one bracket. @jizhihaoSAMA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to concatenate the lists in your loop. If these are normal python lists then `backs += stock_list`

Numpy also has a `concatenate` function https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html

`np.concatenate([backs, stock_list])`

Comment: with ```backs = np.concatenate([backs, stock_list])```, I was able to put them into one braket, worked like a charm. the logic was just like you said: ```backs += stock_list```, thanks a lot chief! @g23